# NextJS React Tailwind CSS Navbar Active Styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

It's been a while since I've fiddled with React and just started learning Next.Js. I'm curious how I would change the background of my Navbar in Tailwind CSS based on the current boolean value "current" true/false on which page the user is on with Next Router.

It seems pretty simple, but it's gotten a little complicated for me to understand. The code is originally from one of the Tailwind CSS examples and there's an array of links with href and the current value with true/false which populates the background when set to true. When you change any of the "true," the background gradient that I want appears, but I have been trying to get it to update on the corresponding page link that's visited.

If anyone can guide me in the correct direction, I'd be very grateful.

Here's my header code:

[/components/header.js](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b8qW)

I've also made a layout component component and wrapped it in my _app.js.

Here's the rest of the code for other components:

[_app.js](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b8qY)

[/components/layout/main.js](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b8qZ)

My Navbar currently looks like this:
[Navbar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu2U8.png)

If you need my other code, I am happy to provide.

Comment: While providing external links is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question as code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than storing **current** in the *navigation* array you could compute it each render based on the current url using `router.asPath` (see the docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter)).

```
const isActive = router.asPath === item.href;
```

--

```
{
  navigation.map((item) => {
    const isActive = router.asPath === item.href;
    return (
      <NextLink key={item.name} href={item.href} passHref>
        <a
          className={classNames(
            isActive
              ? "text-black font-bold bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-300 via-purple-300 to-indigo-400"
              : "text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-500 hover:underline hover:underline-offset-2",
            "px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium font-mono"
          )}
        >
          {item.name}
        </a>
      </NextLink>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for response! When I try and import the const below the navigation.map, it says that JSX expressions must have one parent element. I've import useRouter() at the top level of the function. I've also tried to use the "const isActive" above all functions, and get router is not defined. What should I do differently? I have also tried to put it below "useRouter()" and get item is not defined.

Comment: Actually, thank you! I got it to work. I realized I was missing changing it to the correct arrow function with {} brackets and closing it correctly.  :))