# Highlight the active nav item on click using Tailwind CSS in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, navbar, tailwind-css

I have a navigation bar like this:

```
<nav className="bg-white shadow dark:bg-gray-800">
<div className="container flex items-center justify-center p-6 mx-auto text-gray-600 capitalize dark:text-gray-300">
        <Link
                to="/home"
                className="text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-300 transform dark:text-gray-200 border-b-2 border-blue-500 mx-1.5 sm:mx-6"
        >
                home
        </Link>

        <Link
                to="/invoices"
                className="border-b-2 border-transparent hover:text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-300 transform dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:border-blue-500 mx-1.5 sm:mx-6"
        >
                features
        </Link>

        <Link
        
                to="/forms"
                className="border-b-2 border-transparent hover:text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-300 transform dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:border-blue-500 mx-1.5 sm:mx-6"
        >
                forms
        </Link>

        <Link
                to="/newForm"
                className="border-b-2 border-transparent hover:text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-300 transform dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:border-blue-500 mx-1.5 sm:mx-6"
        >
                form2
        </Link>
</nav>
```

I want to change the nav item when it's clicked, but everywhere in Stackoverflow that I've searched I only found solutions for NestJS, Next.js, etc., not React.

Comment: Change the navItem ? style or content? Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70342961/nextjs-react-tailwind-css-navbar-active-styling

Comment: If you want to style your nav item when It's active and If you're using React-router-dom.
Here is a doc reference use NavLink: https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#navlink

Or If you want to style the nav link on click then use the `active` variant from tailwindCSS : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Comment: What is `Link`? Please edit post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've better context over the code and what it's capable of. If you are using `react-router-dom` then I would suggest using the `NavLink` component as it handles the active link and styling for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `active` variant on className in tailwindCSS.

for example:

```html
<Link
    to="/home"
    className="text-gray-300 active:text-blue-500"
>
    home
</Link>
```

Comment: that's not correct because i want use dynamic path

Comment: You need to use `useLocation` `hook` of `react-router-dom` for finding path and then check if `Link path` and `location path` both are same  `apply classes`.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to define how you want to determine whether the class is added or not first.

Seems to me you'd want to instead loop through your items:

```
const isCurrentPage = (href: string) => {
   // return true if `href` is the current path, many ways you could do this
}

// loop through your items and conditionally add the class if active...
['/home', '/invoices', '/forms'].map(href => <Link key={href} href={href} className={isCurrentPage(href) ? 'active' : ''} />
```

Your `isCurrentPage` function depends on your app logic and setup; you could probably rely on some logic like `window.location.pathname.indexOf(href) === 0` to start.

Answer (score 0):

The NavLink component automatically receives an "active" class by default when it's considered active, allowing you to apply CSS for styling purposes.
So, in your index.css file, add:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.active{
    /* Add whatever CSS style will make your link look active. The example below (in my case) */
    @apply block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white bg-orange-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-orange-700 md:p-0 underline;
}
```

Thats it. Hopefully, this helps!